# Parse to mongoDB atlas connect

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, database-connection, connection-string, database

I'm trying to change my parse.com connection string to a mongoDB cluster and it giving me:

```
Server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
```

I'm using their Connection String:

```
mongodb://username:PASSWORD@cluster0-shard-00-00-xxxx.mongodb.net:xxxx,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxxx.mongodb.net:xxxx,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxxx.mongodb.net:xxxx/admin?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0
```

i've added their ip(54.85.224.0/20) to the trusted ips,I'm using admin to connect. I don't know what else to do, what am i missing? I'm totally new to this so please explain to me like i'm 5!

Comment: Did you work out the issue? I suspect the problem is that you are not connecting with `ssl=true` in your connection string. See [Driver Connection](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/) in the Atlas documentation for more examples. If you're still having connection issues, I would suggest logging into your Atlas account and creating an support ticket for faster assistance (once logged in, there should be a "Support" link in the bottom left of the Atlas UI).

Comment: it's not ssl issue i've added that already but forgot to write it here in the Q, i think the answer down would've solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue, in my case I was trying to connect to a different DB than admin. My problem was that I was changing "/admin" to "/cars" (my DB name) in the connection string.

Customer support kindly helped me out, some facts I learned:

- The authentication is always against the "admin" db.
- You can specify the DB you want to use changing "/admin" to "/cars" but you have to specify the authentication db ("admin" in this case) using the "authSource" parameter in the url.

So you have to change the db name and append "&authSource=admin" to the end of your connection string.

Example:

```
mongodb://username:PASSWORD@cluster0-shard-00-00-xxxx.mongodb.net:xxxx,cluster0-shard-00-01-xxxx.mongodb.net:xxxx,cluster0-shard-00-02-xxxx.mongodb.net:xxxx/admin?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: interesting as i've contacted them with but they got me no reply, I've abandon them for that error and went to self hosted DB on digitalocean instead, wonder if it would've worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Did you ever get this working? i'm getting unsupported URL option "authSource". The string does work for parse-server however is not allowed to be used as a connection string in parse.com migration.